# How to use std::min_element on map with unique pointer values? (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++17, smart-pointers

I have a map with unique pointer values, and want to get a reference to the pair with the smallest value. I'm using the code below to do this, but am getting an error in the line where I call `std::min_element`. The error message is: `no matching function for call to object...`. What should I do to fix this?

```
  using pair_type = std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<int>>;

  std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<int>> map;

  map.insert(std::make_pair("a", std::make_unique<int>(1)));
  map.insert(std::make_pair("b", std::make_unique<int>(2)));
  map.insert(std::make_pair("c", std::make_unique<int>(3)));

  pair_type& min_pair = std::min_element(std::begin(map), std::end(map),
                                         [](pair_type &p1, pair_type &p2) {
                                           return *p1.second < *p2.second;
                                         });
```

Comment: Shouldn't `pair_type` be `std::pair<const std::string, std::unique_ptr<int>>`? Consider using `decltype(map)::value_type` instead.

Comment: or `decltype(map)::reference`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry I'm quite new to C++... Do you mind explaining why I should use `const` in `pair_type`?

Comment: `std::min_element` returns an iterator to the smallest element, not a reference.

Comment: @Jack A map's element type is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`. So you need to add `const` to be able to get the right reference type.

Comment: After swapping all `pair_type` with `decltype(map)::value_type` I now get error: `Non-const lvalue reference to type 'decltype(map)::value_type' (aka 'pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int>>>') cannot bind to a temporary of type 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int>>>>`.

Comment: `std::make_unique` is not C++11, if you allowed C++14 then you can use `auto` in lambda

Comment: Aside: `map.emplace("a", std::make_unique<int>(1));` involves less conversion than `insert(make_pair(...))`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Caleth. How come?

Comment: `emplace` forwards the arguments to a `value_type` constructor. `make_pair` will make a `std::pair<const char[2], std::unique_ptr<int>>`, and then that will be converted by a different `value_type` constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map`'s value type is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, you can't edit the key whilst it is in the map.

```
using map_type = std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<int>>;

map_type map;

map.insert(std::make_pair("a", std::make_unique<int>(1)));
map.insert(std::make_pair("b", std::make_unique<int>(2)));
map.insert(std::make_pair("c", std::make_unique<int>(3)));

map_type::iterator it = std::min_element(std::begin(map), std::end(map),
                                         [](map_type::const_reference p1, map_type::const_reference p2) {
                                           return *p1.second < *p2.second;
                                         });
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Caleth. What's the difference between `map_type::reference` and `map_type::value_type`? In comment above, Francois suggests using `value_type` instead?

Comment: @Jack You would need to use `map_type::value_type` with & like you used your `pair_type`

Comment: @Jack `value_type` is equivalent to a fixed version of your `pair_type`. Using `reference` or `value_type &` is equivalent in this context.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: `map_type::reference` is defined to be `map_type::value_type &`, similarly `const_reference` is defined as `const value_type &`